# Работа с синтезом речи

Tags: android, java

Никто не подкинет ссылок на сайты, где есть примеры работы с синтезом речи в android? На сайте Дарьи Ряжских я ничего не понял, нужно что-то другое, посоветуйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Взгляние на статью блога: [An introduction to Text-To-Speech in Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/search/label/Text-to-Speech). Там по шагам прописано, что нужно сделать, чтобы приложение заговорило.

Comment: Я наверно не так сказал, мне нужно что бы я говорил, а приложение вписывало то что я сказал в эдит вью.)